# call operator of the object that a pointer argument is pointing to from a const function

Tags: c++, constants

define operator

```
    RGBAPixel * operator()(size_t x, size_t y);
    RGBAPixel const * operator()(size_t x, size_t y) const;
```

How should I call it in a const function? (that png on the bottom)

```
PNG Quadtree::decompress() const
{
    PNG * png = new PNG((size_t) res, (size_t) res);
    decompressHelper(png,0,0,res/2,root);
    return * png;
}

void Quadtree::decompressHelper(PNG * png, int x, int y, int setresolution, QuadtreeNode * subRoot) const
{
    if (subRoot->nwChild == NULL) {
        png((size_t) x, (size_t) y) = subRoot->element;
```

Comment: There's a potential memory leak.

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix it? given decompress has to be const

Answer (score 0):

Just define the operator overload as const as well:

```
RGBAPixel * operator()(size_t x, size_t y) const;
                                           ^~~~~
```

Since you're passing by pointer, you should dereference it before calling (don't forget to dereference):

```
*(*png)((size_t) x, (size_t) y) = subRoot->element;
 ^^   ^
```

It's not really a function pointer, but a pointer to a class object that can be used as a function. That's a subtle difference, though.

I also recommend changing this function to prevent a potential memory leak:

```
PNG Quadtree::decompress() const
{
    PNG png((size_t) res, (size_t) res);
    decompressHelper(&png, 0, 0, res/2, root);
    return png;
}
```

You're not `delete`-ing what you've allocated with `new`.

Comment: Sorry I have that const for operator as well. Can you please update your answer?

Comment: how about this line         png((size_t) x, (size_t) y) = subRoot->element;

Comment: (*png)((size_t) x, (size_t) y) = subRoot->element; do you mean use this after change to decompressHelper(&png, 0, 0, res/2, root);?

Comment: @ZHU Yes . . . .

Comment: Then how should I change the declaration of the function?

void Quadtree::decompressHelper(PNG * png, int x, int y, int setresolution, QuadtreeNode * subRoot) const

Comment: @ZHU Why are you passing by reference now?

Comment: So what should I pass to it? still PNG * png?

Comment: But then it says fatal error: expression is not assignable
        (*png)((size_t) x, (size_t) y) = subRoot->element;

Comment: @ZHU Fixed my answer now.